# Nginx active health_checks

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I need to implement active health_check on Nginx Plus. The upstream server represent a k8s cluster and I have exposed traefik 9000 health endpoint. The health check however reports it is not up because nginx checks https://k8s/ping and not http://k8s/ping
On https I get 404 and on http 200.

How can I tell Nginx to use HTTP instead https on the health_check?

Here is the configuration:

```
upstream k8s {
 zone k8s 64k;
 server server1:443
}

match probe {
 status 200;
 body ~ "OK";
}

# Server config
server {
 listen *.443 ssl;
 # server options placeholder

location / {
 proxy_pass https://k8s

 # headers placeholder

 health_check port=9000 uri=/ping match=probe;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following TCP Active Health check

```
stream {
   upstream k8s {
       zone k8s 64k;
       server backend1.example.com:9000 slow_start=30s;
       
   }
   match probe {
    send      "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n";
    expect ~* "200 OK";
   }
   
   server {
       listen  9000;
       proxy_pass http://k8s;
       health_check match=probe interval=10 passes=2 fails=3;
       health_check_timeout 10s;
   }
}
```

You can read more on the [official docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-health-check/)